# How to simulate air resistance for a pendulum?

Tags: java, math, physics

I use the following code to simulate the animation of a pendulum, however, it ignores air resistance and never stops.

```
while (true) {
    angleAccel = -9.81 / length * Math.sin(angle);
    angleVelocity += angleAccel * dt;
    angle += angleVelocity * dt;
    repaint();
    try { Thread.sleep(15); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

Now I want to take into account air resistance so that the pendulum would slow down and finally stops in the vertical direction. I've tried to adapt the code to my need however none of them worked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have tried with the air resistance!

Comment: This isn't a programming problem *per se* but it *is* a modelling problem. It is an interesting question for meta as to whether pure algorithm design is in scope for SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most sensible way to do this, in my opinion, is to build air resistance into the differential equation that governs the system. Air resistance could be approximated by a force proportional to the velocity but in the opposite direction, for example. Then either the equation could be solved in closed form (e.g., damped harmonic oscillator `e^{-kt} sin (wt)`) or could be numerically integrated (a more versatile solution in the long run).

Comment: @rookiedev the force is proportional to `velocity^2` and `velocity^3` depending on the environment (gas,liquid) but if the velocity cross a barrier (this is not the Mach barrier yet) then cavitations and turbulent fluctuations will occur and that complicates thing significantly. Also pendulum usually oscillate in the same area so the layers of surroundings are periodically affected creating oscillations. So the question is what is the target precision? for simple one just take few points along pendulum and add dapening force  `f=-c0*velocity*|velocity|` c0 is small skalar the rest are vectors

Comment: @rookiedev c0 is function of profile area of sampled part of pendulum and environment viscosity ..The velocity is proportional to  Angle velocity and radius position of sampled part of pendulum